# Pick a, b, c randomly without any conditions from the set ${1, 2, 3,..., 2019}$ What is the probability for $abc + bc + c$ to be divisible by 3?

Tags: probability, divisibility

Note: I revisited this problem after I can mostly understand modular arithmetic. Since I was not too satisfied with those answers I decided to try to answer question once again with my own understanding of probability and modular arithmetic (you may see duplicate questions) and I want to know if my answer is correct:

Pick $a$, $b$, $c$ randomly without any conditions from the set $(1, 2, 3,..., 2019)$ What is the probability for $abc + bc + c$ to be divisible by 3?

Suppose $abc + bc + c$ is divisible by 3, then $abc+bc+c = c(ab+b+1)$.

Case 1: $c$ is divisible by $3$. If $c$ is divisible by $3$ then there are $673$ integers from the set that satisfies $c$. Since c is a multiple of 3  then $a$ and $b$ can be any integers from the set. In conclusion, $$P(c) = \frac{1}3, P(a) = P(b) = 1$$

and the probability for case 1 is $\frac{1}3 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \frac{1}3$

Case 2: $ab + b+ 1$ is divisible by $3$. Factoring  $ab + b + 1 = b(a+1)+1$ Then we can utilize modular arithmetic for this case.
$$b(a+1)+1\equiv 0 \pmod3$$
$$b(a+1)\equiv 2\pmod3$$
This is the part where I will use the fact that if $p$ is prime, and $xy \equiv p \pmod n$ then $x \equiv 1\pmod n$ and $y \equiv p \pmod n$ or vice versa. Then we can divide the problem to subcases.

Subcase 1: $$b \equiv 2\pmod 3 \ {and} $$
$$a+1 \equiv 1\pmod 3 \rightarrow a \equiv 0 \pmod3$$

For $b \equiv 2\pmod 3$ there are $673$ integers that satisfies $b$ ($\frac{1}3$ of the set), and for $a \equiv 0 \pmod3$ there are also $673$ integers that satisfies $a$ ($\frac{1}3$ of the set). Note that $c$ can be any integers from the set. Then the probability for subcase 1 is $\frac{1}3 \cdot \frac{1}3 \cdot 1 = \frac{1}9$

Subcase 2: $$b \equiv 1\pmod 3 \ {and} $$
$$a+1 \equiv 2\pmod 3 \rightarrow a \equiv 1 \pmod3$$

For $b \equiv 1\pmod 3$ there are $673$ integers that satisfies $b$ ($\frac{1}3$ of the set), and for $a \equiv 1 \pmod3$ there are also $673$ integers that satisfies $a$ ($\frac{1}3$ of the set). Note that $c$ can be any integers from the set. Then the probability for subcase 2 is $\frac{1}3 \cdot \frac{1}3 \cdot 1 = \frac{1}9$

Then, the total probability will be $\frac{1}3 + \frac{1}9 +\frac{1}9 = \frac{5}9$. My question is, is this the correct answer?

Note: I found where my mistake was. My mistake was, in the second case, I assumed $c$ could be anything (including multiples of 3). But assuming $c$ is a multiple of 3 automatically falls into the first case. Hence, I should've assumed $c$ is not a multiple of 3 in the second case. Then excluding 3, I should multiply $\frac{2}3$ to $\frac{2}9$

Comment: same answer as the set being $\{ 1,2,3 \}.$  It would have involved weights, but 2019 is div isible by 3

Comment: Right. I just noticed that since we can express 4, 5, 6,... to 2019 as 3m+1, 3n+2, 3k for some integers m, n, k

Comment: Adding on to @WillJagy, there are 27 cases total (3 choices for each a b and c). You can do casework from here or make clever observations, such as the whole term is divisible by c, so either c is divisible by 3 or ab+b+1, which simplifies this even further.

Comment: Your case 2 is conditioned on $c$ not divisible by 3, so your subcases should have $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{2}{27}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2019 is divisible by 3 (other than that, it's random), we can instead solve it just for 1,2,3. If $c$ is divisible by $3$, it must be true.

If $3\nmid c$, then we need $ab+b+1$ to be divisible by 3, or $ab+b$ to be 2 mod 3. There are two solutions, modulo 3.

The answer is $\frac 13 + \frac 23 \cdot \frac 29 = \frac{13}{27}$.

By the way, the only thing you did wrong was overcount the cases where both $ab+b+1$ and $c$ are divisible by 3.

Comment: 2019 is not a random number. It is a multiple of 3 by design.

Comment: Sorry, fixed (mentioned it is divisible by 3)

Comment: What does $\frac{2}3$ and $\frac{2}9$ represent? And why are we multiplying them?

Comment: Oh sorry. i get it now. In the second case, i assumed c could be anything (including multiples of 3.) But I already used the fact that c is a multiple of 3 in the first case, hence we exclude 3 from the set and multiply by 2/3